# Alternative to tf2_sensor_msgs.do_transform_cloud in ROS 2[Humble] for Point Cloud Transformation?

Tags: ros2, transform, pointcloud, pcl-ros, velodyne-pointcloud

I am relatively new to working with point cloud data in ROS 2, and I am currently facing an issue with transforming point cloud data. I have been trying to utilize the tf2_sensor_msgs.do_transform_cloud function for transforming point cloud data, but I have discovered that this functionality is not available in ROS 2 humble.

Could someone kindly suggest alternative methods or packages that can achieve the transformation of point cloud data in ROS 2? I am particularly interested in methods that  provide similar functionality to do_transform_cloud.

I appreciate any guidance or recommendations you can provide to help me progress with my point cloud transformation task.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using pcl and pcl_conversions. It allows you to convert ros pointcloud2 to pcl message type, do the transformation you need to and then convert back to ros pointcloud2. If your are going to work a lot with pointcloud data, PCL is you best friend.

Comment: Do you have code snippet for this ? even pcl_conversions is not available in ros2 humble